# Several UITableView's with custom cells. Don't works scrolling

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell

I have two UITableView with custom cells, and am faced with strange behavior.

The tables are periodically updated with new records. I add 20 records to table#1,w ith table#2 still empty. All the records don't fit on the screen, so the table displays with scrolling. Then I add a record to the table#2, and table#1 ceased scrolling (you can only see the first few records that fit on the screen).

After I reload the data for table#1, the problem disappears.

When the cells are not customized, I have no problems with scrolling.

```
#import "MyViewController.h"
#import "MyCell1.h"

@implementation MyViewController
@synthesize table1, table2;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    viewList = [NSMutableArray array];
    viewMemory = [NSMutableArray array];

    [table1 setDataSource:self];
    [table2 setDataSource:self];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSInteger num = 0;

    if ([tableView tag] == 1980) {
        num = [viewList count];
    }
    else if ([tableView tag] == 1981) {
        num = [viewMemory count];
    }

    return num;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyCell1 *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    NSString *someText;

    if (!cell) {
        cell = (MyCell1*)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Cell1"owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    if ([tableView tag] == 1980) {
        someText = [viewList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else if ([tableView tag] == 1981) {
        someText = [viewMemory objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    [[cell value] setText:someText];

    return cell;
}

- (IBAction)ButtonClick:(UIButton *)sender {
    if ([sender tag] == 1980) {
        [viewList addObject:@"0000"];
        [[self table1] reloadData];
    }
    else if ([sender tag] == 1981) {
        [viewMemory addObject:@"1111"];
        [[self table2] reloadData];
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

At the other site I was offered to use beginUpdates - endUpdates instead of reloadData for updates records in the tableviews. All works.